# Why need to mention "Supported by the .NET Compact Framework" for classes members?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, base-class-library

In MSDN documentation, many .NET classes methods (like ArrayList ) mentioned that "Supported by the .NET Compact Framework".

How internally it has been modified so that it has been supported by .NET compact Framework? I assumed all the .NET Base class library can be used on .NET compact Framework.

Answer (score 4):

No, the CF is a subset of the .NET framework so this wording simply indicates that the type in question is part of the CF.  The CF does not include every type - only those that make sense for its purposes.  `ArrayList` is one such type that was included in the CF and is the exact same type as what you are used to working with.

Comment: Thanks, What could be the good reasons not to include whole BCL in CF ?

Comment: If you included the entire BCL, then it wouldn't be "compact", it would be the full framework, now wouldn't it?

Comment: Size and OS limitations are two big reasons.